# Не добавляется 0(NULL)

Tags: ассемблер, строки, masm32, null, masm

Почему у меня не получается вот так вот сделать? Как исправить?

```
.data
mystring  dd ?
 ...
.code
mov mystring, "talf",0
```

Comment: что имеется ввиду под "не получается"? не компилируется (тогда какой текст ошибки), или проверяете в процессе исполнения (тогда как проверяете).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Командой mov нельзя переместить больше 4 байт (на 32-битной платформе). Т.е. `mov mystring, "talff"` будет ошибкой.
2. mov не поддерживает такой способ "копирования", которое вы пытаетесь сделать. `mov mystring, "talf",0` - это, фактически, три операнда.
3. `mystring` у вас двойное слово (4 байта), вы туда хотите вставить 5 байт.

Правильный код будет выглядеть примерно так (синтаксис masm):

```
.data
mystring  db 20 dup (?) ; выделяем место с запасом
 ...
.code
mov dword ptr mystring, "talf"
mov byte ptr mystring+4, 0
```

Comment: А можно сделать как нибудь чуть по универсальнее `mystring+4`?

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy, масса вариантов: 1 - сразу инициализировать `mystring` строкой, 2 - функция `strcpy` из msvcrt.dll, 3 - `rep movs` или `rep movsd`.